# Remove special characters from string to filter data by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "f2025%20%3D%20%2209%3A00%22%20and%20f5118288%20%3D%20%222017-03-31%22#";
```

How can I remove all special characters {'%20%3D%20%22','%3A','%22%20','%20'} from the above string to return list value like this {'f2025', '09', '00', 'and', 'f5118288', '2017-03-31'}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex to split the string

```
%20%3D%20%22|%3A|%22%20|%20|%22#
```

using this [split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var str = "f2025%20%3D%20%2209%3A00%22%20and%20f5118288%20%3D%20%222017-03-31%22#";
var strArray = str.split(/%20%3D%20%22|%3A|%22%20|%20|%22#/)
```

Comment: It work for me. Thank you very much! You save my life

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` with special character and `split` for desire result.

```js
var str = "f2025%20%3D%20%2209%3A00%22%20and%20f5118288%20%3D%20%222017-03-31%22#";
str = str.replace(/%20%3D%20%22/g, "@").replace(/%3D/g, "").replace(/%3A/g, "@").replace(/%22%20/g, "@").replace(/#/g, "").replace(/%20/g, "@").replace(/%22/g, "@");
var Result = str.split('@');
alert(Result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```